# C++ recording PCM stream in Linux

Tags: c, linux, alsa, pcm, recording

I'm playing a .Wav file on Ubuntu's default PCM device and I can hear the PCM sound in headphone, now I need to record the PCM stream(write the PCM data played in that default PCM device into a local file) with C++. I tried ALSA `snd_pcm_readi(capture_handle, buffer, buffer_frames)` method as below, the program works fine but the values in buffer are all 0. I think there're several possibilities:

- I didn't select the right PCM device (but I double checked the Wav file was played in default PCM device and the `snd_pcm_open ()` device argument was indeed "default")
- the ALSA 'capture' method didn't support 'record' from playing PCM stream as [this](http://equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html) mentioned

any help? thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
          
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  int err;
  char *buffer;
  int buffer_frames = 128;
  unsigned int rate = 44100;
  snd_pcm_t *capture_handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hw_params;
    snd_pcm_format_t format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE;

  if ((err = snd_pcm_open (&capture_handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot open audio device %s (%s)\n", 
             argv[1],
             snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "audio interface opened\n");
           
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc (&hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot allocate hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
             snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "hw_params allocated\n");
                 
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any (capture_handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot initialize hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
             snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "hw_params initialized\n");
    
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access (capture_handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set access type (%s)\n",
             snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "hw_params access setted\n");
    
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format (capture_handle, hw_params, format)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set sample format (%s)\n",
             snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "hw_params format setted\n");
    
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near (capture_handle, hw_params, &rate, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set sample rate (%s)\n",
             snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }
    
  fprintf(stdout, "hw_params rate setted\n");

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels (capture_handle, hw_params, 2)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set channel count (%s)\n",
             snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "hw_params channels setted\n");
    
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params (capture_handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set parameters (%s)\n",
             snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "hw_params setted\n");
    
  snd_pcm_hw_params_free (hw_params);

  fprintf(stdout, "hw_params freed\n");
    
  if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (capture_handle)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot prepare audio interface for use (%s)\n",
             snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "audio interface prepared\n");

  buffer = malloc(128 * snd_pcm_format_width(format) / 8 * 2);

  fprintf(stdout, "buffer allocated\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if ((err = snd_pcm_readi (capture_handle, buffer, buffer_frames)) != buffer_frames) {
      fprintf (stderr, "read from audio interface failed %d (%s)\n",
               err, snd_strerror (err));
      exit (1);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "read %d done\n", i);
  }

  free(buffer);

  fprintf(stdout, "buffer freed\n");
    
  snd_pcm_close (capture_handle);
  fprintf(stdout, "audio interface closed\n");

  exit (0);
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the suggestions I just fixed those error. This time the buffer record some noise instead of 0, still not sure if Alsa could record audio from a playing PCM stream

Comment: Does your hardware actually support recording from the playback stream? If not, you have to use PulseAudio.

Comment: Yes I switched to PluseAudio’s module-null-sink as my output device, still haven't figured out if C++ could read/record data from module-null-sink, any hints? thanks.@CL.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio

Comment: I wanna open a `PulseAudio` `module-null-sink` with `ALSA` `snd_pcm_open()` and I saw a [related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139782/what-device-name-should-i-have-to-give-in-snd-pcm-open-other-than-default) from you. The `aplay -L`  listed only hardware devices, no virtual ones. Do you have any idea about getting correct device name of virtual sink for `ALSA` opening? Thanks.@CL.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to capture the output audio to file is to use the built in ALSA file plugin. To do that create a file ~/.asoundrc with the following contents :

```
@hooks [
    {
        func load
        files [
            "~/.asoundrc"
        ]
        errors false
    }
]

pcm.writeFile {
    type file
    slave {
        pcm card0 # Now write to the actual sound card
    }
    file "/tmp/capture.wav"
    format "wav"
}

pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave.pcm "writeFile"
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 0
}
```

It will force alsa to play the audio and save it by default to the /tmp/capture.wav file. Audio will also be output to the card 0 soundcard on your system.

If you really want to write the audio to file as it plays, then you will want to create an ALSA plugin which reads the input audio, then writes it to file as well. This essentially implements the plugin.

If you do want to write your own plugin, then you can start with [this C++ external plugin class provided by gtkIOStream](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/test/ALSAExternalPluginTest.C). You will want to add the audio file output to the "transfer" method in a similar way to the sox.write method in [this audio file capture application](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/applications/ALSACapture.C#L138).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I just find a way to read playing audio stream into C++ buffer.

Comment: ok - Do you want to route all audio through a default C++ ALSA plugin ? In that plugin you can load the output audio into a C++ buffer ?

Comment: Actually I piped the audio output to system input device and use ALSA `snd_pcm_readi` method to read input bytes into C++ buffer.

Answer (score 0):

After several days searching, I finally find a way. There's an audio played in my sound output device and I need to read that PCM stream into C++ buffer for further operation. The former code I post did half of the job, as [this tutorial](http://equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html) mentioned, the`snd_pcm_open (&capture_handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)` method did open default PCM device to read stream data from it, however this `SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE` parameter indicates it opened the `default capture device`(e.g. microphone input) which transform outside analog voice into digital bits for reading, my audio is played in `default playback device`, if I change this parameter into `snd_pcm_open (&capture_handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)` it would read nothing from it. So the another half job is to pipe audio stream played in `playback device` to `capture device` with [pavucontrol](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82259/how-to-pipe-audio-output-to-mic-input), once output stream is piped to `capture device`, I can read it in C++ program.